# Treeview search results flat list

Tags: c#, search, treeview

How can I make the list on the right populate with only items which meet the search criteria? I'm not asking for the literal code necessarily, but just some general guidance on how to do so.

I've already written the code to populate the list on the left with C#, supplying a directory to populate the list from. I was just not clear on how to get the list to populate correctly when using the search field at the top.

Should I just call another function which researches the directory for the files based on the search criteria? or store the initial file list in a variable and search within that to populate the list?

[image]

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace directoryBrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListDirectory(treeView1, @"C:\Windows");
        }

        public void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
        {
            treeView.Nodes.Clear();
            var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));
        }

        public static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
        {
                var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

                foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                     try
                     {
                          directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));
                     } catch {
                          // cannot access directory
                     }
                }
                foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
                }
                return directoryNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is likeley more efficient to work on the data in the RAM (working memory) once you have loaded it. on the other hand: if you scan the file system again and again your search would find new files immediately once they have been created on the file system. IMO this depends on the number of files and your needs

Comment: yeah there would be around 1,000 to 2,000 files.

Comment: ill try doing it by scanning the computer each time, and then i can always switch it to memory after the fact if its to slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a parent node that should be global to the form. so that you can use the parent node without searching the directory (folder) on the harddisk every time. lets say

```
var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
```

and add all the subsequent nodes to the directoryNode as your code already performing this. Finally you get the overall structure added to directoryNode. Add this directoryNode to the treeview. your treeview will be populated. when the user provides search parameter, search in the directoryNode not in the actual directory, in memory searching is fast then searching directory on the hardisk, and create list of nodes and assign to the treeview. when the search parameter is removed by the user assign the directoryNode again.

Hope this suggestion will help

Comment: this sounds like a great idea. Thank you. I'll try this out